# SSAS Processing Threads

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, sql-server-2008, ssas, ssas-2008

We have an SSIS package that executes XMLA against SSAS to delete a database and then rebuild a database  We then create a Windows Task Scheduler job to kick off the SSIS package for each of our clients at a given time interval.  We have anywhere from 50-200 jobs that we would like to run on a nightly basis.

We are having a problem that when too many jobs run together at the same time (anywhere from 3+ jobs) SSAS seems to freeze and these jobs never complete. When I monitor SSAS (via Perfmon) I only see a maximum of two busy processing threads at any one time.  It would seem that with multiple jobs running at the same time, say 10 jobs I should a minimum of 10 processing threads running, but again we don't.  Our server has 8 cores and 32 GB memory and CPU utilization is also fairly low.

Does anyone have any suggestions for using more threads in SSAS or explanation for the behavior I am seeing?

Comment: SQL Server Standard Edition? Cube processing is serial.

Comment: Do you really need to delete the database each time?  Is every schema changing every night?  Unlikely as downstream reports etc would break.  Possibly you can just send ProcessFull to update the data in the existing database.